# Paypal Standard payment not redirecting to Magento Success page after Payment complete

Tags: magento-1.7, paypal, payment-gateway

I am facing problem with paypal standard payment.

Everything is fine until success page. When customer complete payment. Then paypal is not redirecting to Magento success page. It is still is in Paypal page. But charging from customer Paypal account and no payment information is coming to Magento backend and it is showing order as pending.

Comment: What kind of extensions are you running? Anything related to PayPal? Has any core code been edited? I would attempt to reinput all the PayPal credentials in the backend, and also change your theme to the default Magento theme (assuming it has 0 changes) and try to do a checkout.

Answer (score 3):

For redirecting to your store on successful payment at PayPal, you need to set preferences in the PayPal account associated with the store.

For this you need to access the ***PayPal account***, go to ***profile***.
In ***selling tools*** in ***website preferences*** you need to update the settings to redirect to the success page of your store. You need to put

http://www.storename.com/paypal/standard/success/ OR http://www.storename.com/index.php/paypal/standard/success/

based on whether you are using URL rewrites or not.

In the above mentioned link, you need to replace **storename** with the **site name** of your store.

Comment: whats this url for Express Checkout?

Comment: refer to the PayPal link for IPN settings :
https://www.paypal.com/ipn

Comment: what if you have multi store with different domain or sub-folder? what will the return url?